# Arduino Uno Force-Sensitive Resistor

Tags: arduino-uno, resistor

Would any one know how many Force-Sensitive Resistors that a Arduino Uno can handle being hooked up to at one time?

Comment: Theoretically as many as you like. You just have to set your bounds.

Comment: what is `Force-Sensitive Resistor` ..... how does it transmit its data?

Comment: @jsotola: it think he's talking about stretchy bands, like used in the power glove. To answer, about 8 without adding additional complexity or cost to the UNO.